# wireless driver issue for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7857714/ I AM HAVING THE SAME PROBLEM AND AS SUGGESTED I COPIED AND PASTED THE CODE IN THE TERMINAL AND ABOVE IS THE LINK TO THE FILE IT GOT CREATED AS wireless-info.text

basically i am having a wireless driver issue and i read [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/502639#502639) on d above page as in what to do and at the very first point mentioned i am stuck.can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Your device can only use this driver at this time.

Comment: actually his could also use the one from linux-firmware-nonfree and could have limited functionality with the legacy driver

Comment: Post link please.

Comment: my card is a bcm4312, that's why I know what I'm talking about

Comment: and there's a question somewhere on askubuntu that goes into detail I just more or less remember what ones are supported and which ones aren't. I've had 12 computers, 8 dells 3 toshibas and my latest is an acer, each one had a different card but all bcmxx

Comment: only linux generic is unchecked and every other option(fakeroot,dkms,ndiswrapper-common ,ndisgtk,ndiswrapper-utils,libfakeroot,ndiswrapper-dkms)are checked

Comment: As usual you need to do your research and read carefully. His card is BCM43142 and this is what is important [14e4:4365].

Comment: then still what I first recommended works, and is the same as you recommended, bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: Does it look the same or did I add a command before that one so he would be able to find the source file?

Comment: I am trying to help you out hoping you will watch what other people do and learn from it, that is how we all learn. I have a mentor that I still consult with when needed, I also look up my information before I post an answer every time to make sure nothing has changed even though I have been doing this for three years.

Comment: sorry if I insulted you, I read the number and it looked the same as the one for the card in the computer I just set up a couple of weeks ago that I was able to install each of those on and it worked. I've been sequentially installing the drivers since a couple years ago when I got my first one and install ubuntu on it and had to set it up, I went through basically every one and while most of the drivers "worked" some had issues or were very slow, so on my newest computer I had found that all three of those worked but the kernel-source one was optimal

Comment: You did not insult me, everything is okay. There are people like chili555 that you should watch there answers because you will learn a lot. When we post answers we have the responsibility to do everything we can to make sure our answers are correct and that they are in the easiest form possible for people to understand. So we all need to do our research and make sure what we write is correct and that we are not giving wrong information. When I give someone directions to compile a new driver I always compile it first in virtualbox to make sure it compiles without errors and the same with any

Comment: directions I give.So please do research and be careful about the solutions you post, if you need help I will be happy to pm with you and some other people I now would not mind either.

Answer (score 0):

it is a broadcomm bcm4312, so in the terminal while connected to ethernet type this: sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source. linux-firmware-nonfree also seems like it would work for your device